# Facebook Search posts with specific hashtags v2.2

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

We have built an .net application which gets Facebook posts by searching for the specific hash tags we have given.

As Facebook is changing its rules from April 30 2015, which only allows v2.0 or later calls. Is there a way from v2.0 to search for Facebook posts?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is no longer possible since v2.0, because:

> Public Post search is no longer available

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: but is there a way to get posts from specific facebook page?

Comment: you can´t search with the api, but how to get posts from a facebook page with code examples is explained in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed